# Non blocking http request loop

Tags: winapi, pywin32, win32gui

I would like to write a simple systray app which checks the status of some web service and changes its icon according to the response given.
I'm straggling to do it non-blocking way so that the program is still responsive as it fires http requests every 10 sec. Could you help out - I'm a total noob when it comes to winapi ???

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Module     : SysTrayIcon.py
# Synopsis   : Windows System tray icon.
# Programmer : Simon Brunning - simon@brunningonline.net
# Date       : 11 April 2005
# Notes      : Based on (i.e. ripped off from) Mark Hammond's
#              win32gui_taskbar.py and win32gui_menu.py demos from PyWin32
'''TODO

For now, the demo at the bottom shows how to use it...'''

import json
import time
import urllib2         
import os
import sys
import win32api
import win32con
import win32gui_struct
try:
    import winxpgui as win32gui
except ImportError:
    import win32gui

class SysTrayIcon(object):
    '''TODO'''
    QUIT = 'QUIT'
    SPECIAL_ACTIONS = [QUIT]

    FIRST_ID = 1023

    def __init__(self,
                 icon,
                 hover_text,
                 menu_options,
                 on_quit=None,
                 default_menu_index=None,
                 window_class_name=None,):

        self.icon = icon
        self.hover_text = hover_text
        self.on_quit = on_quit

        menu_options = menu_options + (('Quit', None, self.QUIT),)
        self._next_action_id = self.FIRST_ID
        self.menu_actions_by_id = set()
        self.menu_options = self._add_ids_to_menu_options(list(menu_options))
        self.menu_actions_by_id = dict(self.menu_actions_by_id)
        del self._next_action_id


        self.default_menu_index = (default_menu_index or 0)
        self.window_class_name = window_class_name or "SysTrayIconPy"

        message_map = {win32gui.RegisterWindowMessage("TaskbarCreated"): self.restart,
                       win32con.WM_DESTROY: self.destroy,
                       win32con.WM_COMMAND: self.command,
                       win32con.WM_USER+20 : self.notify,}
        # Register the Window class.
        window_class = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
        hinst = window_class.hInstance = win32gui.GetModuleHandle(None)
        window_class.lpszClassName = self.window_class_name
        window_class.style = win32con.CS_VREDRAW | win32con.CS_HREDRAW;
        window_class.hCursor = win32gui.LoadCursor(0, win32con.IDC_ARROW)
        window_class.hbrBackground = win32con.COLOR_WINDOW
        window_class.lpfnWndProc = message_map # could also specify a wndproc.
        classAtom = win32gui.RegisterClass(window_class)
        # Create the Window.
        style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
        self.hwnd = win32gui.CreateWindow(classAtom,
                                          self.window_class_name,
                                          style,
                                          0,
                                          0,
                                          win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                          win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                          0,
                                          0,
                                          hinst,
                                          None)
        win32gui.UpdateWindow(self.hwnd)
        self.notify_id = None
        self.refresh_icon()

        win32gui.PumpMessages()

    def _add_ids_to_menu_options(self, menu_options):
        result = []
        for menu_option in menu_options:
            option_text, option_icon, option_action = menu_option
            if callable(option_action) or option_action in self.SPECIAL_ACTIONS:
                self.menu_actions_by_id.add((self._next_action_id, option_action))
                result.append(menu_option + (self._next_action_id,))
            elif non_string_iterable(option_action):
                result.append((option_text,
                               option_icon,
                               self._add_ids_to_menu_options(option_action),
                               self._next_action_id))
            else:
                print 'Unknown item', option_text, option_icon, option_action
            self._next_action_id += 1
        return result

    def refresh_icon(self):
        # Try and find a custom icon
        hinst = win32gui.GetModuleHandle(None)
        if os.path.isfile(self.icon):
            icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
            hicon = win32gui.LoadImage(hinst,
                                       self.icon,
                                       win32con.IMAGE_ICON,
                                       0,
                                       0,
                                       icon_flags)
        else:
            print "Can't find icon file - using default."
            hicon = win32gui.LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)

        if self.notify_id: message = win32gui.NIM_MODIFY
        else: message = win32gui.NIM_ADD
        self.notify_id = (self.hwnd,
                          0,
                          win32gui.NIF_ICON | win32gui.NIF_MESSAGE | win32gui.NIF_TIP,
                          win32con.WM_USER+20,
                          hicon,
                          self.hover_text)
        win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(message, self.notify_id)

    def restart(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        self.refresh_icon()

    def destroy(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        if self.on_quit: self.on_quit(self)
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0)
        win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_DELETE, nid)
        win32gui.PostQuitMessage(0) # Terminate the app.

    def notify(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        if lparam==win32con.WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
            self.execute_menu_option(self.default_menu_index + self.FIRST_ID)
        elif lparam==win32con.WM_RBUTTONUP:
            self.show_menu()
        elif lparam==win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP:
            pass
        return True

    def show_menu(self):
        menu = win32gui.CreatePopupMenu()
        self.create_menu(menu, self.menu_options)
        #win32gui.SetMenuDefaultItem(menu, 1000, 0)

        pos = win32gui.GetCursorPos()
        # See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/winui/menus_0hdi.asp
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self.hwnd)
        win32gui.TrackPopupMenu(menu,
                                win32con.TPM_LEFTALIGN,
                                pos[0],
                                pos[1],
                                0,
                                self.hwnd,
                                None)
        win32gui.PostMessage(self.hwnd, win32con.WM_NULL, 0, 0)

    def create_menu(self, menu, menu_options):
        for option_text, option_icon, option_action, option_id in menu_options[::-1]:
            if option_icon:
                option_icon = self.prep_menu_icon(option_icon)

            if option_id in self.menu_actions_by_id:                
                item, extras = win32gui_struct.PackMENUITEMINFO(text=option_text,
                                                                hbmpItem=option_icon,
                                                                wID=option_id)
                win32gui.InsertMenuItem(menu, 0, 1, item)
            else:
                submenu = win32gui.CreatePopupMenu()
                self.create_menu(submenu, option_action)
                item, extras = win32gui_struct.PackMENUITEMINFO(text=option_text,
                                                                hbmpItem=option_icon,
                                                                hSubMenu=submenu)
                win32gui.InsertMenuItem(menu, 0, 1, item)

    def prep_menu_icon(self, icon):
        # First load the icon.
        ico_x = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXSMICON)
        ico_y = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYSMICON)
        hicon = win32gui.LoadImage(0, icon, win32con.IMAGE_ICON, ico_x, ico_y, win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE)

        hdcBitmap = win32gui.CreateCompatibleDC(0)
        hdcScreen = win32gui.GetDC(0)
        hbm = win32gui.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, ico_x, ico_y)
        hbmOld = win32gui.SelectObject(hdcBitmap, hbm)
        # Fill the background.
        brush = win32gui.GetSysColorBrush(win32con.COLOR_MENU)
        win32gui.FillRect(hdcBitmap, (0, 0, 16, 16), brush)
        # unclear if brush needs to be feed.  Best clue I can find is:
        # "GetSysColorBrush returns a cached brush instead of allocating a new
        # one." - implies no DeleteObject
        # draw the icon
        win32gui.DrawIconEx(hdcBitmap, 0, 0, hicon, ico_x, ico_y, 0, 0, win32con.DI_NORMAL)
        win32gui.SelectObject(hdcBitmap, hbmOld)
        win32gui.DeleteDC(hdcBitmap)

        return hbm

    def command(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        id = win32gui.LOWORD(wparam)
        self.execute_menu_option(id)

    def execute_menu_option(self, id):
        menu_action = self.menu_actions_by_id[id]      
        if menu_action == self.QUIT:
            win32gui.DestroyWindow(self.hwnd)
        else:
            menu_action(self)

def non_string_iterable(obj):
    try:
        iter(obj)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    else:
        return not isinstance(obj, basestring)

# Minimal self test. You'll need a bunch of ICO files in the current working
# directory in order for this to work...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import itertools, glob

    icons = itertools.cycle(glob.glob('*.ico'))
    hover_text = "SysTrayIcon.py Demo"

    # -------------changed ---------
    def ping_server(sysTrayIcon): 
        while True:
            request = urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost:8080/api/some_end_point')
            data = json.loads(request)
            if data and data['some_value']:
                #change icon
                sysTrayIcon.icon = icons.next()
                sysTrayIcon.refresh_icon()
            time.sleep(10)
            # TODO: how do i do this non - blocking way ???????????


    menu_options = (('Ping server', icons.next(), ping_server))
    def bye(sysTrayIcon): print 'Bye, then.'

    SysTrayIcon(icons.next(), hover_text, menu_options, on_quit=bye, default_menu_index=1)
```

Comment: I haven't touched Python since around '07 and have no idea of the available libraries. If I were to approach this problem in C/C++, I'd be creating a separate thread. In this thread, I'd be doing the web request. I'd then decode the result and create an icon. I would then send a message from this thread to the main window of my program - this would be a custom-message. I'd tell the main window that a new icon was available and the handle for it.

Comment: thanks @enhzflep , your comment gave me some food for thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @enhzflep advice i've spaned thread and achieved desired effect. This is what i've added to SysTrayClass

```
import threading
import time

class Foo(object):

  def __init__(self):
     self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.query_server_threading, args=())
     self.thread.start() 

  def query_server_threading(self):
     while True:
          #json request and data processing
          time.sleep(10)
```